# How to read files in Sharepoint from an online python service?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I would like to know how to read files from Sharepoint to an online Python service such as JupyterLite or Google Colab?

Comment: You specify 'online'. Does that mean you managed to make it working locally? And if so, what did you use? Something along the lines of [this](https://medium.com/@wardarahim25/microsoft-sharepoint-data-transfer-using-python-a7c2721392c)? In other words, you aren't providing much context for what you really have and what you've tried. And JupyterLite isn't 'online'. The files to run it are stored online and then served to your browser which then runs it inside the browser using web assembly. Minor distinction in some ways, but may be important ultimately. Not sure what your goal is either here?

Comment: <continued> (Of course, JupyterLite can easily and cheaply be hosted online because it only requires static file hosting. And thus makes it convenient for hosting alongside data. Maybe that is the direction you are hoping to go?) It may be difficult because of inherent browser security though to accomplish what you plan. I cannot be sure because I haven't worked with sharepoint and Jupyter and cannot tell what you intend from your limited details.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for the reply. Apologies for my poor explanation, I don't have the technical understanding to explain these things properly! The company I work for won't install python on any company infrastructure, so I need to use browser based version of python. Our files are all stored in sharepoint so I need to connect to sharepoint to access any files. Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: That makes sense, but besides Jupyterlite, there's the option of using full Jupyter on a remote computer, which would actually be online Jupyter. You can set your own up on Amazon web services or use PythonAnywhere.com. Those both can be used for just Python in your browser, too. (Pythonanywhere.com being the easiest of those two options.) Maybe I too quickly misread 'online Python service' as 'online Jupyter service' since the two options you list after are `.ipynb` related..  Or does your company block remote things from accessing your sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master) to connect sharepoint online. You can refer to following code to read a file

```
"""
Demonstrates how to download a file content
"""

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_team_site_url, test_client_credentials

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_client_credentials)
file_url = 'SitePages/Home.aspx'
file = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("Site Pages").root_folder.files.get_by_url("Home.aspx")
file_content = file.get_content().execute_query()
print("[Ok] file content has been downloaded")
```